# I´m trying to create elements dinamically on javascript and inserting them on my HTML, but the tag <br> just don´t work

Tags: javascript, html

I´m working on a for that create HTML elements than insert them into my page dinamically.

```
for (let i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    var res2 = document.getElementById("res2")

    var divCriada = document.createElement("div")
    divCriada.className = "divname"
    divCriada.innerHTML = "abc"

    res2.appendChild(divCriada)
    
    var input   = document.createElement("input")
    input.className = "input"

    let divInserida= document.getElementsByClassName("divname")
    divInserida[i].appendChild(input)

    var br = document.createElement("br")
    res2.appendChild(br)
}
```

Notice that, the code is doing exactly what it was made for:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iI5lk.png

All 26 divs are being created correctly, but the line break just don´t work! you can see right ahead!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/974lD.png

I don´t know what to do, i don´t find any answer anywhere =(

i´m new to this world, maybe it could be a gross mistake by me, but if you find it i would aprecciate a lot if you explain what you did and why mine is not working.

Comment: Does your `res2` element has a CSS rule `display: flex`? If that's the case set it back to `block` should fix it: `document.getElementById("res2").style.display = 'block'`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add CSS Style on #res2

```
#res2 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```